# Making values of a variable mapped to some ID uniform

Tags: r

OK - so I have a data frame in R that looks pretty much like this:

```
  id  age v1 v2 ...
12345  31  
12345  32  
12345  32
```

I'd like to be able to look at all the IDs in this DF, and set all values of `age` mapped to a particular `ID` to the first (or lowest, in this case, as a consequence of how the DF is ordered) value of `age` corresponding to that `ID`. So the example above would become

```
  id  age v1 v2 ...
12345  31  
12345  31 
12345  31
```

I have a feeling that this could be done with plyr (or similar), although my brain's fried right now, and I realise perhaps that might not be the best way to go about it, nor might it be the most straightforward. Any suggestions? TIA.

Comment: Do you have to keep the number of rows the same?  If not, then a simple `tapply(age,id,FUN=min)` would do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, plyr will get the job done.

```
  > dt
      id age
    1  1  20
    2  1  21
    3  2  25
    4  2  26
    > ddply(dt, .(id), transform, age = min(age))
      id age
    1  1  20
    2  1  20
    3  2  25
    4  2  25
```

Answer (score 4):

This is for "first", although you may have wanted "lowest".

```
ave(dat$age, dat$id, FUN=function(x) head(x, 1))
[1] 31 31 31
dat$age <- ave(dat$age, dat$id, FUN=function(x) head(x, 1))
```